# How to know type of value of given key in redis in node js

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am doing a small project using redis and node js - redis client '[node_redis](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-redis-node-js/)'.
The problem is that, to get the key's value there are different get function like for string and integer type there is client.get, for array type there is client.lrange() etc. 
So how to identify what function to use to get the value if the desired value type is not known, is there a way to identify the value type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [TYPE](https://redis.io/commands/type) command.

2022 redis v4 - ES with `await`:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis'

async function go(){
  const client = createClient()
  client.on('error', console.error)
  await client.connect()

  const value = await client.TYPE('key')
}
```

redis v3 Promises:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const redis = Promise.promisifyAll(require('redis'))
const client = redis.createClient()
client.on("error", err => console.log("Error " + err))

client.typeAsync('foo').then(res => {
  console.log('type: "%s"', res)
})
.finally(()=> {
  client.quit()
})
```

redis v3 callbacks:

```
const redis = require('redis')
const client = redis.createClient()
client.on("error", err => console.log("Error: %s", err))

client.type('foo', (err, res) =>{
  if (err) return console.log('Error: %s', err)
  console.log('type: "%s"', res)
  client.quit()
})
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with sync ?
for example:
var type = client.type('foo');

Comment: @MikeBrianOlivera Not that i'm aware of, there are a few generic ways to turn async api's into sync but you generally shouldn't use sync methods as they will block the process while accessing redis.

Comment: could you help me with that please, it's for tesing mode. 
I tried your code and return None :(

Comment: @MikeBrianOlivera Put it in a question with the code you have tried and what you get/expect

Answer (score 0):

Usually your application should know in advance the type of value that it is accessing using a given key name. That said, there's the Redis [`TYPE`](https://redis.io/commands/type) that you can use for inspecting a given key's type.